# How do I decrease padding in the bookmarks bar on Chrome v68?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

It seems that with Chrome v68 which came out this week, the padding on my [bookmarks bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrikB.png) has been increased, and has subsequently caused me to have fewer bookmarks available on the bar. I try to keep short descriptions on each one of my buttons (the first two are the Jira Plan and Jira Work pages) so I can fit more on the screen.

Is there any startup flag in Chrome that allows me to set this padding, or a flag that I can disable?

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple solution so far. Report the issue to the google team. maybe they will listen if more people will complain. A more complicated solution: to develop an extension with functionality of Chrome Bookmark Manager but with normal spacing option. I'm not 100% sure if that is possible with Chrome though.

How to report an issue in Chrome: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: An explanation how to report the issue would be a great addition to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it can be changed:

**A refined look for the bookmarks bar**

*The material design on the bookmarks page and extensions page can't be turned off any more using flags. Also, the bookmarks bar is now touch friendly. It takes up more space by having padding around the icons and text.*

One potential solution would be to use bookmarks bar folders to group related sites (i.e. a folder for Jira, DT, etc.) Simply right click on the bookmarks bar to create a folder which you can then setup to contain your desired links using the bookmark manager. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. This is awful. I have quite a few bookmarks on my bookmarks bar, all without titles. With Chrome 67, I had space for 2 or 3 more. With Chrome 68, the entire bookmarks bar is filled, and I have 8 bookmarks in the overflow area.

Answer (score -1):

Someone must have been listening, this magically appears to be fixed in Chrome v68.0.3440.84 !